# How can I check on the value of a template variable?

Tags: templating, debugging

If I'm used to PHP's `var_dump()` and `print_r()` to check the value of a variable, how can I evolve to inspect things in Craft where Twig's `dump` isn't available?

Comment: In what cases would Twig's dump() function not be available? You mean just when Dev Mode isn't enabled?

Comment: Yes, that is apparently what I mean. I've learned something, but now I feel a bit daft.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's [the dbug plugin](https://github.com/lukeholder/craft-dbug) which should give you what you are after, template side.

> This plugin adds a helpful dbug method to your Craft templates. This
>   will help you see in the dark - figure out what kind of variables you
>   are dealing with, and what methods they implement.

Comment: The dbug plugin isn't supported anymore, and Luke (the author) recommended [craft_kint](https://github.com/mildlygeeky/craft_kint) instead.

Answer (score 22):

If you have devMode set to "true" in your config files, you can use "dump" in a twig template like this without any plug in needed:

```
{{ dump(myArray) }}
```

Comment: Tip: `devMode` is enabled by adding `'devMode' => true` to `craft/config/general.php`.

Answer (score 7):

There's a plugin called "craft inspector" https://github.com/adrianmacneil/craft-inspector that has come in handy.

```
{{ craft.request | inspect }}
{{ inspect(craft.request) }}
```